# Jenkins agent can't get started

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I set up Jenkins on a linux server and select a Win7 pc as an agent. I choose "launch slave agents via java web start" in agent configuration. when I use following command to start the agent, the Jenkins agent window showed connected and then at once turned to "terminated". Anybody help? Thanks a lot!

```bsh
set SLAVENAME=%1
set CYGPATH=%2
if x%CYGPATH% == x set CYGPATH=C:\APPS\cygwin\bin

set PATH=%CYGPATH%;%PATH%

:RUN_SLAVE
echo %PATH%
javaws %MASTER%/computer/%SLAVENAME%/slave-agent.jnlp
exit 0
```

Comment: What happens if you run `javaws ...` from a command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that my drive was not set. I told it to use the D:\ Drive because I had cloned it from another machine. However that drive didn't exist (Coudln't access it to place down the files).

Answer (score 1):

There could be many things that are wrong, but because you report the connection is established and then terminated, I think you have an incorrect address for Jenkins itself in the Jenkins global configuration.

Jenkins does not use the "Jenkins URL" setting for a lot of things, but establishing connection with Java Web Start slaves is one of them, so please ensure "Jenkins URL" in the master configuration is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out there so that it might be useful for someone...

I also had the same issue and on checking the Master log (nice place to start if you have this issue), I came to know that the Remote FS Root was wrong. Actually I was following the [official tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) and even on the tutorial, they suggest you to use "C:\Jenkins\" which is wrong!

Jenkins tries to copy some files to this path but in this case, inverted commas are not accepted. So setting it to C:\Jenkins\ worked out for me!