# Why does my Jenkins Slave Java Web Start Require Sudo?

Tags: jenkins

I get symptoms similar to [jenkins slave can't get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287845/jenkins-slave-cant-get-started) except my slave is a Mac, my master is a linux box, and I've discovered that running the javaws https-blah-blah.jnlp command only works if I use sudo.

**How can I investigate this and get to the point of not needing sudo?** When I run javaws, I only see a tiny Jenkins slave agent window. Is there a log file somewhere -- or is there a verbose mode?

Comment: Any chance you can run the mac slave via ssh?

Comment: Alas the work done by my jobs cannot be done headless.